# get too many request in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, performance, asp.net-mvc-4, grimport

I have a project with ASP.NET MVC at the end, I Installed Glimpse and get a log, the result log was stange. I have 24088 requests. 
[image]

How can I know where request call? I have just about 15 css and js files and about 5 action call.

How can I decrease these requests ?

Comment: That's not 24 thousand requests, it states it takes 24 seconds to process your request (note the "ms").

Comment: It seems that you have two Db Queries that only take 108 milliseconds but your view should be looked at because it takes 5 seconds to render it.

Comment: @CodeCaster thanks .

Comment: @CodeNotFound view render took too long . how can I decrease that ?

Comment: If your views doesn't do any logic that take too long time, I mean they just use model passed by the Controller, then you should look about your JS files. I haven't the exact answer. Al depend on the content of your view.

Answer (score 1):

if most of your requests are for css and java script then use bundling and minification feature, it will reduce your request count and improve the performance.

for CSS create style bundle and script bundle see the example for mode details

```
 public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles){
 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
             "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
     // Code removed for clarity.
```

}

refer [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification) for mode details

Comment: refer link for more details https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification